# .NET port of OGNL Library

Tags: c#, open-source, ognl

Does anyone know of a good .NET port of the [OGNL library](http://www.opensymphony.com/ognl/) here?  It looks like I could use something like this and the only one I have found so far is on SourceForge [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ognlnet/) and hasn't been updated since 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been looking for something like this as well. Unfortunately, there isn't anything I'm aware of that's feasible for use in a real project. Sorry!

One suggestion that might be of help is to e-mail the author directly. Oftentimes, they abandon the project because they've found that another existing project's work is more in line with what they were trying to accomplish.

Comment: That's a bit discouraging :(  

I did correct the error I was having with OGNL.NET but it's written in .NET 1.0 and It would be cool to update it to generics